# How to login with Google on AWS project in flutter

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, google-authentication

I'm using [amazon_cognito_identity_dart_2](https://pub.dev/packages/amazon_cognito_identity_dart_2) for handling the authentication in my flutter app and I finished the auth with email now I want to finish the Google auth as well, and was following the **Use case 19** in the packages documentation but I've encountered an error, it doesn’t load the **SignIn page** of Google, I've added the **COGNITO_POOL_URL**(us-east-1_XXXXXXXXX) and ** COGNITO_CLIENT_ID**(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX) in the url it doesn’t work still, is there something that I'm missing here?

P.S. I'm using Getx for state management

What it displays in mobile:

[image]

What it displays in web when I run the url:
[image]

How I call the function:

```
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () async {
                                  Get.to(
                                    () => Scaffold(
                                      appBar: AppBar(),
                                      body: controller.getWebView(),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
```

**Documentaiton**:

Use case 19. Using this library with Cognito's federated sign in on mobile devices. Use flutter_webview (https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) to navigate to Cognito's authorize URL. Use flutter_webview's navigationDelegate to catch the redirect to myapp://?code=<AUTH_CODE>. Make a POST request to Cognito's token URL to get your tokens. Create the session and user with the tokens.

```
final Completer<WebViewController> _webViewController = Completer<WebViewController>();
  Widget getWebView() {
    var url = "https://${COGNITO_POOL_URL}" +
      ".amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?identity_provider=Google&redirect_uri=" +
      "myapp://&response_type=CODE&client_id=${COGNITO_CLIENT_ID}" +
      "&scope=email%20openid%20profile%20aws.cognito.signin.user.admin";
    return
      WebView(
        initialUrl: url,
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) ' +
            'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Mobile Safari/537.36',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _webViewController.complete(webViewController);
        },
        navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
          if (request.url.startsWith("myapp://?code=")) {
            String code = request.url.substring("myapp://?code=".length);
            signUserInWithAuthCode(code);
            return NavigationDecision.prevent;
          }

          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        },
        gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
      );
  }

  final userPool = CognitoUserPool(
    'ap-southeast-1_xxxxxxxxx',
    'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  );
  static Future signUserInWithAuthCode(String authCode) async {
    String url = "https://${COGNITO_POOL_URL}" +
        ".amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=" +
        "${COGNITO_CLIENT_ID}&code=" + authCode + "&redirect_uri=myapp://";
    final response = await http.post(url, body: {}, headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      throw Exception("Received bad status code from Cognito for auth code:" +
          response.statusCode.toString() + "; body: " + response.body);
    }

    final tokenData = json.decode(response.body);

    final idToken = CognitoIdToken(tokenData['id_token']);
    final accessToken = CognitoAccessToken(tokenData['access_token']);
    final refreshToken = CognitoRefreshToken(tokenData['refresh_token']);
    final session = CognitoUserSession(idToken, accessToken, refreshToken: refreshToken);
    final user = CognitoUser(null, userPool, signInUserSession: session);

    // NOTE: in order to get the email from the list of user attributes, make sure you select email in the list of
    // attributes in Cognito and map it to the email field in the identity provider.
    final attributes = await user.getUserAttributes();
    for (CognitoUserAttribute attribute in attributes) {
      if (attribute.getName() == "email") {
        user.username = attribute.getValue();
        break;
      }
    }

    return user;
  }
}
```

P.S. I'm using the same code just filling the requested dynamic var-s

Comment: What is the error you see when url is loading?

Comment: I just updated my question, pls have a look.

Comment: Check that your authorize url is correct: https://cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<your user pool ID>/.well-known/openid-configuration returns your configuration.

Comment: My url looks like this:                                                                                          
```var url = "https://${_userPool.getUserPoolId()}" +
        ".amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?identity_provider=Google&redirect_uri=" +
        "myapp://&response_type=CODE&client_id=${_userPool.getClientId()}" +
        "&scope=email%20openid%20profile%20aws.cognito.signin.user.admin";``` can you point out if there is something wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

The format of authorize endpoint is following:

```
https://<your_domain>.auth.<region>.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize
```

The discovery document (configuration for the certain pool inc. authorize endpoint) is found from the url below:

```
https://cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<pool_id>/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

Comment: How does this help me open a webview of google authentication?

Comment: Looks to me that authorize url in the code is wrong.